# Regex: int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, regex

I have written some Java code to retrieve rows from a database and check them for errors:

```
    boolean checkID = ID[findrow].matches("[0-9]+");

    if(checkID==true)
    {   System.out.println("ID is valid");
    }   else
    {   System.out.println("ID is invalid");
    }
```

But the error "int cannot be dereferenced" is shown

I have also tried:

```
    boolean checkID = ID[findrow].toString().matches("[0-9]+");

    if(checkID==true)
    {   System.out.println("ID is valid");
    }   else
    {   System.out.println("ID is invalid");
    }
```

as I am aware that Regex may not check integer values, yet the same error shows..

How is Java code written to Regex check an integer value of numeric values only?

findrow is declared with:

```
findrow = rs.getRow();
```

ID is declared with:

```
final int[] ID = new int[500];
ID[findrow] = rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: How is `ID` declared?  (Also `findrow`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID[findrow]` is probably an `int` on which you cannot call the `toString()` method.

Therefore try: `boolean checkID = Integer.toString(ID[findrow]).matches("[0-9]+");`

Comment: What do you expect that condition to check? It's equivalent to `boolean checkID = ID[findrow] >= 0;` - except the latter is considerably simpler to understand.

Comment: Which is still silly because the only way .matches() would ever be false is if toString() has a minus sign in it, i.e. it's < 0.  I think the basic problem is that the questioner thinks he's dealing with a string of digits that could be invalid and needs to be validated, rather than an actual `int`.

Comment: I agree that the condition is silly. I just gave a technical answer.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that `ID` is declared as `int[]`, which means that `ID[findrow]` is an `int` - so you can't call `matches` or `toString` on it. That certainly gives *exactly* the error message you've specified, in JDK 7:

```
int[] array = new int[1];
String text = array[0].toString();
```

Error message:

```
Test.java:8: error: int cannot be dereferenced
        String text = array[0].toString();
```

But if that's the case, you know that you've got an `int` anyway, so there's no point in checking whether it only contains digits. (You could check that it's non-negative.)

I suspect you're a bit confused about the kind of data you've got here, and what you're meant to be checking it for.

As a couple of points of style, comparing with `boolean` constants is generally frowned upon, and your bracing style is at least unconventional. I'd write your `if` statement as:

```
if (checkID) {
    System.out.println("ID is valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("ID is invalid");
}
```

... or just use a conditional expression:

```
System.out.println("ID is " + (checkID ? "valid" : "invalid"));
```

Comment: I don't think it is safe to make that assumption. Surely he would be getting a different kind of error if that was the case, don't you think?

Comment: And if `ID` really is an `int[]`, it wouldn't make much sense to check if its toString() matches `[0-9]+`.  That would be equivalent to `ID[findrow] >= 0`.

Comment: @JoshM I just tried it and that's exactly the error I'm getting.

Comment: @JoshM: That's the *only* kind of deferencing in the question, and it produces the *exact* error message reported.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, that's interesting. I never would've expected an error message like that one, my apologies.

Comment: @ajb: I completely agree that it makes no sense, but I suspect the OP is basically a bit confused at this point.

Comment: @Jon I know my formatting is unconventional, yet knowing where blocks of code line up is for me understanding how sections of code are distinguished from one another. I find reading and debugging code easier this way :)

Comment: @user2521443: Yes, but you're not the main audience of code on your own question on Stack Overflow, are you? You should be making it easy for *other people* to read, which basically means following common conventions. (I'd also suggest that following common conventions and getting used to them will make it easier for you when you work in teams...)

Comment: I have learnt a lot of Java from the book 'Java In Two Semesters' which formats its code in a similar fashion to the above. I actually find the conventional format somewhat illogical.

Comment: @user2521443: I find it sad for a book to teach unconventional habits :( Regardless of your personal preferences, you need to understand that if you're going to write Java professionally in a team, you're likely to have to follow one of the more common conventions.

Comment: 100% agreed a book should format its code how it was designed to be written. Understood, consistency is essential for professional coding. & thx for the boolean tip :)

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that `ID[findrow]` is returning an `int` type value, which means it doesn't makes sense to have the `.matches()` call, since the `.` operator means to "dereference" and `int`s are primitive types that cannot be dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now that we know ID is an int[], I think we need to address the basic misunderstanding here.  The elements of ID have type `int`, which is a *number*.  It's not "a string of text characters that's supposed to look like a number", or anything like that.  It's really, honestly, a *number* (to be precise, an integer number in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647), and there aren't any characters in it.  So "validating" it by making sure the characters are all digits doesn't actually make sense, since there aren't really any characters.

Comment: The integer is retrieved from a a MySQL DB, so even before the data is retrieved it must conform to the database specifications of a numeric value in the ID field. The code is purely to illustrate Regex checking and part of the task is to validate all fields in the database.

Comment: @user2521443 But part of *whose* task?  You have an `int`.  If this was stored as text in the DB, somebody else had to validate it *before* the text was converted to an `int`.  Maybe MySQL validated it.  If you still have to do some validation, then maybe you need to check that the `int` is > 0 and < some maximum, but it does not make sense to validate an `int` using a regex.  If this is a homework assignment and you're supposed to validate an `int` using a regex, then either you misunderstood the assignment or your teacher was not thinking.

Comment: For absolute integrity, I would check all fields in the DB regardless of whether someone or some specification had validated it previously. I understand that the int could be retrieved and checked using an if statement to see whether it is within a certain range etc but I have Regex checking for the other fields and it seemed like common sense to use the same methodology for the ID. Additionally, I had not encountered this dereferenced error previously.

Comment: Well, you have the right attitude with regard to validation.  I applaud you, and I certainly don't want to discourage this.  But no, the same methodology doesn't work on all types.  If you use toString() on an integer, you will *always* get nothing but digits, except for a possible minus sign in front; there is no other possible outcome.  If there was any bad data in the file, that bad data will have disappeared by the time you get the `int` (assuming you get it at all, instead of an exception being thrown).  So it's just too late to do that kind of validation.